Merging tags admin action result in TemplateDoesNotExist
Following the docu's step: 3. Use the dropdown action list and select Merge selected tags and then click Go,
I get the error below.
Any ideas where I should start to investigate?
Otherwise taggit works like a charm.
django-taggit 6.0
TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/taggit/tag/merge-tags/

admin/taggit/merge_tags_form.html

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8001/admin/taggit/tag/merge-tags/
Django Version:     4.2.16
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

admin/taggit/merge_tags_form.html

Exception Location:     /home/abc/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-xy011hf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py, line 19, in get_template
Raised during:  taggit.admin.merge_tags_view
Python Executable:  /home/abc/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-xy011hf/bin/python
Python Version:     3.8.12

